# Add transitive dependency aar file android Ziggeo

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to add ziggeo library to my Xamarin project.As the library is available only in android I am trying to generate a aar file by adding dependency in build.gradle file.

But the aar file generated do not contain any ziggeo apis.Could you please help me to generate aar or jar file with dependencies included.

```
dependencies {                                                                
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'                        
implementation 'com.github.ZiggeoJitpackService:Android-SDK:0.73.10'      
  }
```

My project build.gradle contains

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

}

More details about ziggeo is available in 
https://github.com/Ziggeo/Android-Client-SDK

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to mention that by sending an email to support (support [at] ziggeo.com) you can get quick reply back with helpful insight or suggestion, so we (I work at Ziggeo) suggest it as we are always happy to help :)

I might be mistaking, however based on this:

> As the library is available only in android

It seems that you missed other mobile SDKs that are available, so I will list them here:

iOS Objective C: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/ios

iOS Swift: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/swift

Cordova: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/cordova

React Native: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/react-native

Ionic SDK: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/ionic

I do suggest however checking this page as well: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/mobile/ since that one will be updated with the links to other, new SDKs that get created.

For example, and what might be good news for you is that Xamarin SDK will be available publicly in about 2-3 weeks from now.

- Looking at all the tasks that are already done, I would presume that it will be available even sooner however that is still the aimed release time.

Now, going to the actual steps to help you with your questions.

The following pages might be of help in general:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/

You would need the aar file, which you need to download directly for the version that you are after. For example: https://jitpack.io/com/github/ZiggeoJitpackService/Android-SDK/0.73.10/Android-SDK-0.73.10.aar

If new version comes out at the time someone is reading this, or if you are after specific version of the Android SDK the following pattern can be used:

https://jitpack.io/com/github/ZiggeoJitpackService/Android-SDK/{{*version*}}/Android-SDK-{{*version*}}.aar

Where `{{_version_}}` would be changed to the specific version you are after.

Now for the above mentioned version you will also need one of the transitive dependencies which you can grab from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.danikula/videocache/2.7.0

The next step would be to create Xamarin binding project and place the Ziggeo `aar` file into the `Jars` folder and select `LibraryProjectZip` in Build Action for the `aar`,

Next you should add subbinding project for the current binding and do the above point actions and link this subbinding in References in the binding project.

- The links to docs above can help with these details.

In the `Metadata.xml` for binding (Ziggeo) add the following:

```
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.ziggeo.androidsdk.widgets.cameraview']/
   class[@name='AspectRatio']/
   method[@name='compareTo' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.ziggeo.androidsdk.widgets.cameraview.AspectRatio']]
   /parameter[1]"
   name="managedType">
   Java.Lang.Object
 </attr>

 <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.ziggeo.androidsdk.widgets.cameraview']/
   class[@name='Size']/
   method[@name='compareTo' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.ziggeo.androidsdk.widgets.cameraview.Size']]/
   parameter[1]"
   name="managedType">
   Java.Lang.Object
 </attr>
```

In the `Metadata.xml` for subbinding (Videocache) add the following:

```
  <attr
   path="/api/package[@name='com.danikula.videocache.file']/
   class[@name='LruDiskUsage.TouchCallable']/
   method[@name='call']"
   name="managedReturn">
   Java.Lang.Object
  </attr>
```

After that build the project and you are set :)